# Arrays and For loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

i have a problem implementing a for loop and storing the resultant values in an array. please have a look at my code below:

```
$pv_numbers = array();


$a=100;//these numbers are just examples, the variables are obtained from some code
$b=5;
$c=10;


for( $d = 0; $d<=($a/$b); $d++ ) {    // $a/$b should define the maximum $d number allowed
     $f=(($a-($d*$c))/$b)  ;        //$f should be cover all those values from $d=0 to max

    $pv_numbers[] = $f;              //then the values stored in an array for use on another function
  }



?>
```

the code seems to store the last value of $d in the array.

Comment: Is this `php`..can you specify the programming language?

Comment: yes Hackerman, it is php

Comment: should go with $d<=(int) ($a/$b); first for proper typecasting

Comment: nice point here Megan, but it gives me an error in Dreamweaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you var_dump($pv_numbers) you get 20 values starting at 20 and ending at -20 effectively subtracting 2 each time.

array(21) {
  [0]=>
  int(20)
  [1]=>
  int(18)
  [2]=>
  int(16)
… 
 [19]=>
  int(-18)
  [20]=>
  int(-20)
}

Let's take a look at the first couple of iterations

$f = ((100-(0*10))/5)
// $f is 20

$f = ((100-(1*10))/5)
// $f is 18

Continues the loop for 20 iterations or until $d <= 20 ($a/$b)

You may be referring to the key which would be equal to the value of $d not because of $d but because it adds a key each time you call $pv_numbers[] = $f and $d is adding one (thanks to the $d++) each iteration.

Is this not what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: thanks for the key clarification tlays. the code is actually working that way, i would like it  to terminate when $f reaches 0. no negative values for $f. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, you will replace value of `$d` with the current iteration.

In your code, `$pv_numbers` will contains all the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this if you need only from 0 to maximum value.

  for( $d = 0; $d<=($a/$b); $d++ ) {   
     $f=(($a-($d*$c))/$b)  ;       

    // $pv_numbers[] = $f;        
    if ($f>=0) {
        $pv_numbers[] = $f;
        continue;


    }
  }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($pv_numbers);
echo "</pre>";
```